# How to get json body data inside request module callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here after returning data form third API I want `bodyData` inside callback method, I want that data to do further processing in side callback of request module
Here is my example snippets

```js
request({
    url: "http://example.com/",
    method: "post",
    json: bodyData,
}, (err, response, apiData) => {
  //   i want bodyData which i had passed it 
})
```

Comment: Did you try to store `bodyData` in global variable and accessing that variable in you success function call?

Comment: You are using request module. right?

Comment: above request module call are inside "getAvailData" function i am calling that function multiple time and value of bodyData each time varied.

Comment: Yes, I am using request module

Comment: I am expecting bodyData inside response object of request module even that will resolve my problem but but i wouldn't get if i JSON parsed it

Answer (score 0):

```
var bodyData = {}; //Global variable

request({
    url: "http://example.com/",
    method: "post",
    json: bodyData,
}, (err, response, apiData) => {
    console.log(bodyData); //You will get the value here
})
```

This will work unless the `bodyData` is changed by some other code before the callback is executed.

If your `bodyData` changes, then wrapping the whole `request` function inside another function will introduce a new scope for the callback function to operate and hence the `bodyData` value used when calling the function will be available.

See the code below.

```
var bodyData = {}; //Global variable

function request_wrapper(bodyData) {
  request({
      url: "http://example.com/",
      method: "post",
      json: bodyData,
  }, (err, response, apiData) => {
      console.log(bodyData); //You will get the value here
  })
}

request_wrapper(bodyData);
```

Comment: ya, actually body data get changed each time i am calling it at multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can get bodyData inside the callback:

```
request({
    url: "http://example.com/",
    method: "post",
    json: bodyData,
}, (err, response, apiData) => {
  console.log(bodyData); // available at this point 
});
```

Since you passed it in you will be able to access it. Better yet you can simply store it in a variable and use the variable inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I used the clone module now it's working

```js
var bodyData = {}; //Global variable

function request_wrapper(bodyData) {
  request({
      url: "http://example.com/",
      method: "post",
      json: bodyData,
  }, (err, response, apiData) => {
      console.log(bodyData); //You will get the value here
  })
}

request_wrapper(bodyData);
```